# How to restrict a combobox to show only few records coming from the store

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5, extjs6, sencha-architect

I have a grid panel with columns which are editable out of those column one of them has an editor type combobox . so this combobox i have a store which is returning data. From the data returned i want to populate only few records records which contain parameter example: x == true. so basically I have check every record and if the records x value is true I should populate it in the combobox. Else it should not show in the dropdown. I have a sample fiddle  [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22ft)

Please help me solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the store, like:

```
filters: [{ property: 'canSee', value: true }]
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/22fu&view/editor